# Sprite Kit zRotation iPhone 4S bug

Tags: ios, iphone, sprite-kit

The following code works normal when testing on iPhone 5S and iPhone 4, but when testing on iPhone 4S the _playerSprite spins uncontrollably around. It also has some glitches when tested on iPhone 4S.

```
     const float AngleBlendFactor = 0.06f;
    _playerAngle = angle * AngleBlendFactor + _playerAngle * (1.0f - AngleBlendFactor);
    _playerSprite.zRotation = SK_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(_playerAngle);
```

I use this code to slowly animate change of player sprite angle.

Thanks in advance

Comment: For sake of platform compatibility use double, not float. zRotation is CGFloat. CGFloat is double on 64 bit (5S) and float on 32 bit (5C and earlier) devices. Probably not related to your issue but I thought I'd mention it because not using the proper types **can** result in behavioral differences between 64 and 32 bit devices. Note that performance-wise double and float are (for common intents and purposes) the same on all devices.

Comment: There's probably some other code then just this. Is this being called in the updates method?

Comment: Its been called from - (void)update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime
When I comment the last line, there is no more glitches, no more spinning but of course angle doesn't update too.

Comment: @JohnRiselvato yes, the problem was in another method but they only shared update method together.

Comment: so you solved the problem?

Comment: yes, I solved the problem by changing method that moves the background. But I don't know what I really do that solved the issue.